# Removing Unwanted Eigenvalues, Twisted bilayer Graphene Hofstadter Butterfly

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am plotting eigen values of a matrix. I want to remove unwanted eigenvalues from the plot. For try run this is possible to manually remove these unwanted eigen values. But for actual run this is not possible.
Here is my code,

```
W = 110;
θ = π/90;
kd = θ;
ϕ = (2*π)/3;
l = 0.5;
m = 3;
n = 2;
y = kd*l^2;
Δ = Sqrt[3]/2*y;
k1 = y/l^2;
k2 = (2*π)/Δ;
v = 120;
s = 3;
H[θ_] := v Sqrt[n + 1]*Exp[-I*θ]
h[θ_] := v Sqrt[m + 1]*Exp[-I*θ]
Td[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (-I*((kd*l)/2))^(n - m)
Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[-I*kd*y] Exp[-4 π*
I*α*j]
td[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (+I*((kd*l)/2))^(n - m)
Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[+I*kd*y] Exp[+4 π*
 I*α*j];
Tn[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (Sqrt[3] (kd*l)/2 + I*((kd*l)/2))^(
n - m) Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[I*k2*Δ] Exp[
I*(kd*y)/2] Exp[π*I*α (2 j - 1)];
tn[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (Sqrt[3] (kd*l)/2 - I*((kd*l)/2))^(
n - m) Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[-I*
 k2*Δ] Exp[-I*(kd*y)/2] Exp[-π*
 I*α (2 j - 1)];
 Ud[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (-Sqrt[3] (kd*l)/2 + I*((kd*l)/2))^(
n - m) Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[-I*k2*Δ] Exp[
I*(kd*y)/2] Exp[π*I*α (2 j + 1)];
un[α_, j_] := 
Sqrt[Factorial[m]/Factorial[n]] (-Sqrt[3] (kd*l)/2 - I*((kd*l)/2))^(
n - m) Exp[-((kd*l)^2/2)] LaguerreL[m, 
Abs[n - m], ((kd*l)/Sqrt[2])^2] Exp[
I*k2*Δ] Exp[-I*(kd*y)/2] Exp[-π*
 I*α (2 j + 1)];
Du1[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{H[θ], Td[α, j], h[-θ], 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ]}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], 4*s];
Du2[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{Td[α, j], Td[α, j], 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ]}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}}];
Du3[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{Td[α, j], 0, 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 0}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}}];
Du5[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{0, 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 0, 0}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 4}}];
Du6[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 0, 0}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 4}, {4*s - 5}}];
Du7[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 0, 0, 0}, {j, 0, 
  s - 1}]], {{4*s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 
  4}, {4*s - 5}, {4*s - 6}}];
du1[α_] := 
Delete[Flatten[
Table[{H[-θ], td[α, j], h[θ], 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ]}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], 4*s];
 du2[α_] := 
 Delete[Flatten[
 Table[{td[α, j], td[α, j], 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ]}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}}];
  du3[α_] := 
  Delete[Flatten[
  Table[{td[α, j], 0, 
  Tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ] + 
   Ud[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ], 0}, {j, 0, s - 1}]], {{4*
  s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}}];
  du5[α_] := 
  Delete[Flatten[
  Table[{0, 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[+I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 0, 0}, {j, 0, 
  s - 1}]], {{4*s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 4}}];
  du6[α_] := 
  Delete[Flatten[
  Table[{tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 
  tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 0, 0}, {j, 0, 
  s - 1}]], {{4*s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 
  4}, {4*s - 5}}];
  du7[α_] := 
  Delete[Flatten[
  Table[{tn[α, j + 1]*Exp[I*ϕ] + 
   un[α, j + 1]*Exp[-I*ϕ], 0, 0, 0}, {j, 0, 
  s - 1}]], {{4*s}, {4*s - 1}, {4*s - 2}, {4*s - 3}, {4*s - 
  4}, {4*s - 5}, {4*s - 6}}];
  b[α_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du1[α], 
  Band[{1, 3}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du2[α], 
  Band[{1, 4}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du3[α], 
  Band[{1, 6}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du5[α], 
  Band[{1, 7}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du6[α], 
  Band[{1, 8}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> Du7[α], 
  Band[{2, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du1[α], 
  Band[{3, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du2[α], 
  Band[{4, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du3[α], 
  Band[{6, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du5[α], 
  Band[{7, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du6[α], 
  Band[{8, 1}, {4*s, 4*s}] -> du7[α]}, {4*s, 4*s}];
  Block[{getEv}, 
  getEv[α_?NumericQ] := 
  getEv[α] = Sort@Eigenvalues[b[α]];
  getEv[α_?NumericQ, n_] := getEv[α][[n]];
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[getEv[α, n], {n, 4*s}], {α, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Dotted]]
```

The unwanted eigenvalues are straight lines. I have drawn a rectangle around it.
[image]

Another issue is for large values s=30 it gives noise. Look at the picture. The arrow regions should be not showing any points. These are hofstadter butterfly for twisted bilayer graphene.[image]

This will be really great if these issues are resolved. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your "noise" eigenvalues aren't actually straight in the $s=3$ example, they do oscillate around the values, with interactions as the other eigenvalues approach them. For instance, when $s=3$, around $\alpha = 0.17$ two of the otherwise flat eigenvalues spike up from $~-210$ to $~-170$. And they appear to be genuine eigenvalues of the matrix `b[\alpha]` if you check that they satisfy the appropriate equation.